# How to create request using retrofit simple xml converter?

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I want to create xml soap request using retrofit simple xml converter. I am using retrofit 2.1. I tried but the order of **Header** and **body** got changed. Please have a look at the below outputs. 
Any help in this would be very appreciated. 
Thanks.

[**Github Code Link**](https://github.com/asanchezyu/RetrofitSoapSample)

**Expected Output**

```
<x:Envelope
xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:gmt="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/Webservice">
<x:Header>
    <gmt:SessionHeader>
        <gmt:sessionId>?</gmt:sessionId>
    </gmt:SessionHeader>
    <gmt:CallOptions>
        <gmt:client>?</gmt:client>
    </gmt:CallOptions>
    <gmt:DebuggingHeader>
        <gmt:categories>
            <gmt:category>Db</gmt:category>
            <gmt:level>None</gmt:level>
        </gmt:categories>
        <gmt:debugLevel>None</gmt:debugLevel>
    </gmt:DebuggingHeader>
    <gmt:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
        <gmt:allowFieldTruncation>false</gmt:allowFieldTruncation>
    </gmt:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
</x:Header>
<x:Body>
    <gmt:user_authenticate>
        <gmt:username>test@test.com</gmt:username>
        <gmt:password>test</gmt:password>
    </gmt:user_authenticate>
</x:Body>
```

**Actual Output**

```
<x:Envelope
xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:gmt="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/Webservice">
<x:Body>
    <gmt:user_authenticate>
        <gmt:password>test</gmt:password>
        <gmt:username>test@test.com</gmt:username>
    </gmt:user_authenticate>
</x:Body>
<x:Header>
    <gmt:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
        <gmt:allowFieldTruncation>false</gmt:allowFieldTruncation>
    </gmt:AllowFieldTruncationHeader>
    <gmt:CallOptions>
        <gmt:client>?</gmt:client>
    </gmt:CallOptions>
    <gmt:DebuggingHeader>
        <gmt:debugLevel>None</gmt:debugLevel>
        <gmt:categories>
            <gmt:category>Db</gmt:category>
            <gmt:level>None</gmt:level>
        </gmt:categories>
    </gmt:DebuggingHeader>
    <gmt:SessionHeader>
        <gmt:sessionId>?</gmt:sessionId>
    </gmt:SessionHeader>
</x:Header>
```

Comment: Why don't you use [kSOAP2 library](http://kobjects.org/ksoap2/index.html)?

Comment: Can I use ksoap2 with retrofit? I just want to update the serialization order.

Comment: Hi, please post the code which you have already tried according to this :    http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: added Github code link in question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use something like following

```
@Order(elements = {"Header", "Body"})
```

Comment: Getting error : org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Ordered element 'Header' missing for class com.asanchezyu.retrofitsoap.api.model.requestlogin.AuthenticateRequestEnvelope

Comment: You may need to add "x:" namespace prefix